# Accessing elements by type in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, types, element, document

A while ago I was making some test in JavaScript,
and played with a code to get the text of all elements with a certain class.

Now I was trying to make something like this but obtain all elements by a certain type, for example all elements `type="text"`

Is there any way to do this in JavaScript or should I use jQuery?

```
var xx = document.getElementsByClassName("class");
for (i=0;i<xx.length;i++){
    var str=xx[i].innerHTML;
            alert(str);
}
```

Comment: You can try document.getElementsByTagName(tagname). Another thing is - iQuery is javascript, so anything possible with jQuery is also possible without it.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

In plain-old JavaScript you can do this:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for(var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    if(inputs[i].type.toLowerCase() == 'text') {
        alert(inputs[i].value);
    }
}
```

In jQuery, you would just do:

```
// select all inputs of type 'text' on the page
$("input:text")

// hide all text inputs which are descendants of div class="foo"
$("div.foo input:text").hide();
```

Comment: I used this to get the submit button.

Answer (score 126):

If you are lucky and need to care only for recent browsers, you can use:

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]')
```

"recent" means not IE6 and IE7

Comment: This method is really well supported now: http://caniuse.com/#search=querySelectorAll

Comment: document.querySelector('input[type=text]') for single element.

Answer (score 4):

The sizzle selector engine (what powers JQuery) is perfectly geared up for this:

```
var elements = $('input[type=text]');
```

Or

```
var elements = $('input:text');
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]") ||
(function() {
    var ret=[], elems = document.getElementsByTagName('input'), i=0,l=elems.length;
    for (;i<l;i++) {
        if (elems[i].type.toLowerCase() === "text") {
            ret.push(elems[i]);
        }
    }

    return ret;
}());
```