# Javascript file overiding another javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Is there any way to select all checkboxes without using any js file. Beacuse whenever i use jquery 1.8.3 or jquery 1.7.2. My other js file don't run or may be due to some problem they don't run. So, I have checkboxes in gridview and i want to perform check All option.

```
 <asp:GridView Width="96%" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="left" ID="gridimages" Font-Size="13px" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="15px" runat="server"  OnSorting="gridimages_Sorting" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowSorting="true" CssClass="grid gridimages" HeaderStyle-BorderColor="#D0D0D0" AlternatingRowStyle-BorderColor="#D0D0D0" RowStyle-BorderColor="#D0D0D0" OnRowDataBound="gridimages_RowDataBound" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="50" PagerSettings-Mode="NumericFirstLast" OnPageIndexChanging="gridimages_PageIndexChanging" CellPadding="3" BorderColor="#D0D0D0" BorderStyle="Groove" BorderWidth="1px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gridimages_SelectedIndexChanged" GridLines="both">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775"/>
     <%--   <RowStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />--%>
        <Columns>

            <asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="20px" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="14px" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="Black">
          <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSelectAll" class="checkAll" runat="server" Text="" onclick="SelectAllCheckboxes(this);"  />
        </HeaderTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>      <div style="text-align: left;">
                   <asp:HiddenField ID="hdn_id" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("Id") %>' />

                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxImage" CssClass="CheckBoxImage1"  onClick="CheckBoxImage();" runat="server" /></div>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

javascript code:

```
           function SelectAllCheckboxes(chk) {
        var gvcheck = document.getElementById('<%= gridimages.ClientID %>');
        var i;
        //Condition to check header checkbox selected or not if that is true checked all checkboxes
        if (chk.checked) {
            for (i = 0; i < gvcheck.rows.length; i++) {
                var inputs = gvcheck.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('input');
                inputs[0].checked = true;
            }
        }
            //if condition fails uncheck all checkboxes in gridview
        else {
            for (i = 0; i < gvcheck.rows.length; i++) {
                var inputs = gvcheck.rows[i].getElementsByTagName('input');
                inputs[0].checked = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Look at the javascript code. I am having problem in the var inputs. I want the id of the CheckBoxImage in var inputs but not able to do. What do i have to change in var inputs line to get the id of checkboximae. Please help.

Comment: Selecting multiple checkboxes in the way you describe requires Javascript. There's no other way to do it.

Comment: Then tell me how to do it with jquery 1.8.3

Comment: have you ever tried to write "inputs" to console to see what is in there?

Comment: It shows
[object HTMLCollection]

Answer (score 0):

Just don't do it with jquery.
Use plain javascript which doesn't conflict with any of your files.

check this answser for selecting elements by types with plain js
[accessing-elements-by-type-on-javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897122/accessing-elements-by-type-on-javascript)

While looping through these elements, you can use the property .checked=true for each element.

Comment: Ok.. i am trying this your way

Comment: Look at my question again please. I have done little change in javascript code

Comment: Every time you loop, you create a new var inputs.
Just create it once outside of your loop (var inputs = []) and use it like any other array inside your loop. inputs[i].checked.

Comment: @user2829939
`// It will get all elements by tagname input
var inputs = getElementsByTagName('input');

// Iterate through all elements by type inputs
for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    // Change the check value for each element
    inputs[i].checked = false;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Use pure javascript.

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkall" /><br />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" />
<input type="checkbox" class="check" />
```

**Javascript**

```
var chkAll = document.getElementById("checkall");
chkAll.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    setCheck(this.checked);
});

function setCheck(value) {
    var items = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var itemLen = items.length;
    for (i = 0; i < itemLen; i++) {
        if (items[i].getAttribute("class") == "check") {
            items[i].checked = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Demo code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qymkT/)

Comment: of course this is just a demo with pure javascript, you can apply the same approach with your code. I'm willing to help, but I do not have aspx installed, sorry.

Comment: Look at my question again please. I have done a little change in javascript code.