# Using JS how can I select a HTML 5 element?

Tags: javascript

Edit: I am totally new to JavaScript. I've spent ages looking to solve my issue, but don't know the right words or phrases to ask the 'correct' question. Other vaguely similar questions are not at all clear and not as specific as my question: how to select the nav.

I have some JS to add a class to my `<nav>`:

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
       var element = document.getElementById("myDIV");
       element.classList.add("mystyle");
    }
</script>
```

This means I have to add an ID to my `<nav>` resulting in

```
<nav id="myDIV">
```

Is there a way to not have to add an ID to the `<nav>`? For the JS to select the `<nav>` element without having to add an ID?

I guess it would be something like this:

```
   var element = document.getElementByType("nav");
```

Comment: `var element = document.getElementByTagName("nav")[0];` Where 0 would be index of element in whole document.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing elements by type on javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897122/accessing-elements-by-type-on-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you could use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), which takes a CSS selector as a parameter

```
   var element = document.querySelector("nav");
   element.classList.add("mystyle");
```

---

If that `nav` is a child of e.g. a `header`, you could add its selector to grab only `nav` that is within such parent

```
   var element = document.querySelector("header nav");
   element.classList.add("mystyle");
```

It is situations like the latter where it really excel's with its CSS selector parameter

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> var element = document.getElementByType("nav");
> ```

The method you are looking for is [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) which returns a list of all the elements with a matching tag name.

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("nav");
var first_nav = elements[0];
console.log(first_nav);
```

```html
<nav></nav>
```

You could also use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) which returns the first element matching a [CSS selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/).

```js
var first_nav = document.querySelector("nav");    
console.log(first_nav);
```

```html
<nav></nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use getElementsByTagName or querySelector

```js
document.getElementsByTagName("nav")[0].classList.add("mystyle");
document.querySelector("nav").classList.add("mystyle2");
```

```css
.mystyle {
  color: red;
}

.mystyle2 {
  font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<nav>Nav</nav>
```